# Anonymizing Datasets

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data-cleaning

I would like to know what are the best practices for anonymizing datasets? 
Ideally I should be able to get the original data back after performing analysis on the anonymized dataset. Should I be using some encryption functions? Hashing maybe?

Comment: Not really clear what you want since if you make it generally reversible, it has not been anonymized . You probably have a user/role model and a consumption model in mind, but you need to explicitly describe this in the question. As well as taking Franck's answer into consideration.

Answer (score 4):

You should make the difference between the following concepts:

- [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) = encoding information in such a way that only authorized parties can read it.
- [data anonymization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_anonymization) = removing personally identifiable information from data sets, so that the people whom the data describe remain anonymous.
- [de-identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-identification) = preventing a person’s identity from being connected with information, while preserving identifying information which could only be re-linked by a trusted party in certain situations (unlike data anonymization which aims to be irreversible).

Your choice depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for laying out like this. Yeah.. what I was looking for was de-identification.